# Selecting item from dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown

I need to use selenium to select an item from a dropdown. The site looks like this

```
 <div class="chosen-drop">
  <div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div>
  <ul class="chosen-results">
     <li class="active-result style="" data-option-array-index="0">Please choose your main activity</li>
     <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">Animals and Pets</li>
     <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-indexx="2">Art and Culture</li>
     <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">Babies</li>
     <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">Beauty and Personal Care</li>
     <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="5">Cars</li>
     <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="6">Computer Hardware and Software</li>
        </ul>
```

How can I select/click on "Cars"/data-option-array-index="5"?

Comment: what did you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use a simple css selector to get element you want using :nth-child. For example to get 2 entry you could write such selector:

.choosen-drop ul>li:nth-child(2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like, as I know java so I write code in java. First List all the locators in `LIST`, then using For- Each and If else you can select particular item and perform operations

```
//Locate all elements in list
List<WebElement> dropEle= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='chosen-results']//li"));
for (WebElement tempEle : dropEle) {
//condition to check text
            if(tempEle.getText().contains("Cars"))
            {
             // Do operations
                System.out.println("Pass");
            }
        }
```